# How to split on commas and then remove the commas in a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split on commas, and then remove the commas. I start out with  a dataframe with 2 columns that I read in from a csv file.

[name]  [feature1, feature2, feature3] - the features are all in one cell and each row may have a different number of features.

I made a sub-df from the main df with this code(pulled out the 2 columns i want for this):

```
df_features =df.loc[:,['name','features']]
```

Then split on the features column to separate them with this code:

```
df_features_split = df_features.features.str.split(expand=True,)
```

It splits the features into their own columns which is what I want, but leaves the commas after the text. I want to get rid of it. I tried:

```
df_features_split=df_features_split.replace(',', '')
```

but it does not remove the commas, I think maybe it needs to be more specific, but I'm not quite sure.any help would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of my df before it was split. Sorry, I hope the format is okay. There are 2 rows of the df.

```
1   The Beehive Loop Trail  beach,  dogs-no,    forest, lake,   views,  wild-flowers,   wildlife
2   Cadillac North Ridge Trail  dogs-leash, forest, kids,   partially-paved,    views,  wild-flowers,   wildlife
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you add a sample of your dataframe pre-split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close to the answer. What you miss is the `pat` argument of [pandas.Series.str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

```py
df_features_split = df.features.str.split(pat=',', expand=True)
```